# How to export field's default image in Features

Tags: features

I have Image field type and provide Default Image. This default image doesn't seem to be exported by Features. Is there another module that need to be added so the image also exported? Or are there another way or alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible yet, there's an issue about this:

[Support imagefield default images](https://drupal.org/node/1439136)

A workaround using hook_field_default_fields_alter() is explained, but be aware is not working completely (Feature seems to be overriden).

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Default image ft](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_image_ft) module looks like it is what you need.

> Remember when you wanted to featurize that default image for that profile picture? Yeah, that's not possible, because the feature would save a fid in its code, and we all know it's not good to have id's in features. Plus, the website manager might want to change the default profile picture.